# Visualizing emoji data in R studio

Tags: ggplot2, rstudio, emoji, network-analysis

This is a very general inquiry about working with emoji data in R studio.

I previously finished a project with emoji data, and the hardest thing I found was visualizing emojis in R studio. I tried to run a co-occurrence network analysis with emojis, but I couldn't visualize the result (emojis were shown as squares in the plot).

I tried emojifont and emo packages, and none of them worked.

Are there other packages that help visualize emojis or analyze emoji data?

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried with some reproducible data using `dput`?